# To convert MCQ's from eiken test format to gift format - PYTHON

Tags: c#, python, .net

I'm trying to convert a text file with MCQ's [Question + Options {A,B,C,D}] in eiken format to gift format.

**Level 1 - Below is the foresaid Eiken Format file:**

Which of the following statements are TRUE about the .NET CLR?

1. It   provides   a   language-neutral   development   &   execution
   environment.
2. It ensures that an application would not be able to
   access memory that it is not authorized to access.
3. It provides services to run "managed" applications. The resources are garbage collected.
4. It provides services to run "unmanaged" applications.

A. Only 1 and 2 
B. Only 1, 2 and 4 
C. 1, 2, 3, 4 
D. Only 4 and 5 
E. Only 3 and 4 
 
ANSWER: C

**Level 2 - The required format which is needed so as to obtain GIFT format, is as follows:**

Which of the following statements are TRUE about the .NET CLR? 
 
It   provides   a   language-neutral   development   &   execution environment.
It ensures that an application would not be able to access memory that it is not authorized to access.
It provides services to run "managed" applications.
The resources are garbage collected.
It provides services to run "unmanaged" applications.
 Only 1 and 2
 Only 1, 2 and 4
 *1, 2, 3, 4
 Only 4 and 5
 Only 3 and 4

*The above format is needed to be given as input to a tool which shall give me the data in gift format.*

**Level 3 - The gift format is as follows, which the tool shall do for me if I get the above format:**

::1::Which of the following statements are TRUE about the .NET CLR? provides language-neutral development & execution environment.It ensures that an application would not be able to access memory that it is not authorized to access.It provides services to run "managed" applications.The resources are garbage collected.It provides services to run "unmanaged" applications. { 

    ~Only 1 and 2

    ~Only 1, 2 and 4

    =1, 2, 3, 4

    ~Only 4 and 5

    ~Only 3 and 4 
}

Any help would be highly appreciated, so as to convert my data from Level 1 to Level 2. As the tool which I have can help me to get from Level 2 to Level 3.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please clafiry what exactly is the **_gift_** format? Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry: Sir, it has been updated in the question now.